# Calculadora de uma P.A em python

Tags: python

```
print('='*50)
print('Digite X para calcular o que você não sabe em um P.A')
print('='*50)
a1=int(input('Digite o 1° Termo:'))
r=int(input('Digite a RAZÃO da P.A:'))
an=int(input('Digite o ULTIMO termo:'))
n=int(input('Digite a quantidade de termos:'))
if n=='x':
    numerotermos=(an-a1+r)/r
    print('O numero de termos da P.A é {:.0f}'.format(numerotermos))
if an=='x':
    ultimotermo=a1+(n-1)*r
    print('O ultimo termo da sua P.A é {:.0f}'.format(ultimotermo))
```

Ainda estou no processo. O problema é como colocar um 'X' `(um termo desconhecido)` para o programa calcular, sendo que eu precisaria que ao mesmo tempo ele fosse 'str' e 'int'.

Ainda estou no curso básico de python, então qualquer sugestão para melhorar o código é bem vinda.

desde já obrigado!

Comment: Se você quer que a entrada possa ser o caractere 'x' então você não deve tentar converter a entrada para int antes de garantir que tal entrada seja efetivamente uma cadeia de caracteres numéricos.

Comment: Uma P.A. é uma sequência na qual a diferença entre um termo `N` e o seu antecedente `N - 1` é sempre uma constante `r`. E, para calcular uma P.A. utilizamos a fórmula `(An = A1 + (n - 1) * r)`. Portanto devemos saber o que de fato temos de calcular. Se `An` ou `A1` ou `n` ou `r`.

Comment: Neste caso, devemos primeiro saber o que queremos calcular para, em seguida, derivar a fórmula e calcular a variável desejada.

Answer (score 0):

Se o problema é que 'X' seja hora 'str' hora 'int', então trabalhe com todos sendo 'str', e quando você descobrir qual é igual a 'x', converta os outros em 'int'

```
print('='*50)
print('Digite X para calcular o que você não sabe em um P.A')
print('='*50)
a1=input('Digite o 1° Termo:')
r=input('Digite a RAZÃO da P.A:')
an=input('Digite o ULTIMO termo:')
n=input('Digite a quantidade de termos:')

#método lower() para caso o usuário digite 'X' invés de 'x'
if n.lower()=='x':
    #a condição acima sendo satisfeita, o número de termos é a informação desconhecida; 
    #podemos converter o restante em inteiros
    a1, r, an = int(a1), int(r), int(an)
    numerotermos=(an-a1+r)/r
    print('O numero de termos da P.A é {:.0f}'.format(numerotermos))

#elif invés de if porque o programa só deve tentar verificar o próximo condicional se a condição do anterior não for satisfeita
elif an.lower()=='x':
    a1, r, n = int(a1), int(r), int(n)
    ultimotermo=a1+(n-1)*r
    print('O ultimo termo da sua P.A é {:.0f}'.format(ultimotermo))
```